# Why do I receive crash report with argv in this example?

Tags: c, file, visual-studio-2017, argv

TL;DR

• 1. Why that code giving crash error as it start?

• 2. What `argv[]` do? Is it receive your cmd input? And how it differentiate from `argv` 1,2,3...so on?

• 3. Output not showing what is expected when I change `argv[1]` with `VSF.txt`

The following code gives an error:

```
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\fopen.cpp
Line: 30
Expression file_name != null_ptr
```

[image: error image]

The idea is to print every file line with the respective number. I don't fully understand files yet and I believing `argv[1]` is what you write at your compiler prompt, is that right? How it differentiate with argv 1,2,3...and so on?

If I change `argv[1]` with `VSF.txt` (the file name) it shows strange chars (not what is inside `VSF.txt`)

[image: VSF.txt image]

[image: cmdoutput]

The output is showing everything with just one line, no space and line variable not incrementing; why it isn't printing the content of `VSF.txt`?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = stdout;
    int lines = 1, start = 1;
    char ch;

    if ((file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Impossivel de abrir o arquivo :%s", argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    while (ch = fgetc(file) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
            start = 1;
        }
        else if (start == 1)
        {
            printf("%d: ",lines);
            putchar(ch);
            start = 0;
        }
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: You don't check that you have a non-null `argv[1]` before you use it.  How are you invoking the program?  What argument(s) are you providing?  Since you do check that your `fopen()` succeeded (very necessary!), the problem must be that you're running the program with no arguments and `fopen()` is objecting to being called with a null pointer by crashing (as it is allowed to do).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry i didnt understand what you asking

Comment: What do you type on the command line when you run your program?  Or what arguments have you given it when you run it from your IDE?  Unless you provide it with a file name, it is going to crash.  Since it crashes, it is probable that you have not provided it with a file name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i cant type it just crash

Comment: So you are not providing it with a file name — check `if (argc != 2) { …print error message and exit… }` or `if (argv[1] == NULL) { …print error message and exit… }` or similar, and do so before you call `fopen()`.

Comment: Do you launch it via F5 (or Ctrl+F5) in Visual Studio, or do you launch it via a cmd.exe console?

Comment: The error message in the first image (please don't post images for text messages) contains "Assertion failed …\fopen.cpp — filename != nullptr" — confirming what I diagnosed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler doesnt the first "if" in the code accomplish that? or should i use both? argc and argv[1]

Comment: @manuell i run via ctrl + f5 in visual studio

Comment: The crash happens because you pass a null pointer to `fopen()` — and the crash happens before `fopen()` returns.  Your `if` test is too late.  You need another one before it.

Comment: Find out how to supply VSF.txt as an argument to the program that is run when you type `control-F5' in Visual Studio.  There'll be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the strange output is here:

```
while (ch = fgetc(file) != EOF)
```

The inequality operator `!=` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So the expression above is the same as:

```
while (ch = (fgetc(file) != EOF))
```

This assigns `ch` a boolean value, either 0 or 1.  That's why you get the output you get.  Put parenthesis in the proper place:

```
while ((ch = (fgetc(file)) != EOF)
```

As for the crash, that is happening because you're not telling the program the name of the file you want to open when you run it.  If you run it from a command prompt, do so like this:

```
archives VSF.txt
```

If you run it from inside Visual Studio, go to the project settings, and under Debugging set Command Arguments to VSF.txt.